# mysql-select a random row from each id

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table in my db which has 2 columns: `id` and `color`. each `id` may have multiple rows with different values for `color`. so for example:

```
id     color
--------------
1      black
1      white
1      green
2      yellow
3      red
3      black
```

I want to select only one row for each `id`, but randomly. I have already tried to use two select queries, but it always returns the first row of each id. what is the problem?!

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM collections ORDER BY RAND()) AS a
GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.color = (select t2.color
                 from t t2
                 where t2.id = t.id
                 order by rand()
                 limit 1
                );
```

For performance, you can try an index on `(id, color)`.

Your code should simply not work.  It uses `select *` with `group by` -- meaning that you have unaggregated columns.  That should be a compile-time error.

EDIT:

LOL.  Of course, the above has an issue.  The subquery gets called for each row, giving each row an opportunity to be in the result set.  Sigh.  Sometimes code doesn't do what I want it to do.  One solution is to seed the random number generator.  This is "arbitrary" but not "random" -- you'll get the same values on each run:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.color = (select t2.color
                 from t t2
                 where t2.id = t.id
                 order by rand(concat(t2.id, t2.color))
                 limit 1
                );
```

If you don't have too many colors, you can use a `group_concat()` trick:

```
select t.id,
       substring_index(group_concat(color order by rand()), ',', 1)
from tA quick and dirty solution is to seed the random number generator:
group by id;
```

Comment: thanks. but for some ids, it returns more than one row and every time I run it, it returns different number of rows as result

Comment: @Soheil . . . This would return multiple rows only if a `color` had more than one row.  Your sample data has no such examples, so this fits the question that you asked.  If an issue, you can use a primary key instead of `color` (which your sample data does not have).

Comment: no, the color values are unique in the entire table. but still this query returns multiple rows for some ids

Comment: @Soheil . . . Arrgh.  It is instructive why it doesn't work.